# How to set up form for a hash in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, parameters, form-for

I have some data associated with a model that is in a hash. The hash is generated in the controller: `@hash`.

What is the proper way to create a form for this data?

I came up with the following code for the view:

```
  <% @hash.keys.each do |key| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label key %><br />
      <%= text_field_tag "hash_" + key, @hash[key] %> 
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

This generates the form, but it creates each hash item as a separate variable in the form. This doesn't seem to be the proper way to submit the data back. I would like to get the data back as a hash, and access it with `params[:hash]`.

What is the best way to do this?

Working in Rails 3.07, Ruby 1.9.2.

Thanks.

EDIT: I should have made this clear. This code is inside of a form generated for a model. So, the form needs to submit all the fields for the model, plus the above hash.

Comment: where does this hash come from ? if you can do it, stick with using AR objects, or do what @lucapette suggested.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. My object comes from a Dry-Validation model/object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20141114035424/http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6371-action-controller-parameters) you should change the name in text_field_tag to

```
<% @hash.keys.each do |key| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label key %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag "hash[" + key + "]", @hash[key] %> 
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: more info on this here: [undestanding parameter naming conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 2):

My answer is not strictly on topic but I really recommend you to take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model. You could use ActiveModel APIs to simulate a model object with Rails 3. Doing that you could simply do something like

```
<%= form_for(@object) %>
```

and leaving the populating of your object to Rails APIs.

Comment: agreed, but maybe this hash is a symptom of bad practice. Asked him for more precision.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure if that approach will work because this code is actually inside of a form generated for a model.

Comment: Then you could try to use to use a fields_for... to be honest I haven't tried it but I don't see any particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the helpers that end with `_tag` that's what happens.

Instead of `text_field_tag ...` use `f.text_field ...`.

In order to get a hash like `params => {:hash => {:field1 => "", :field2 => ""}}` you have to pair up `form_for` with `f.input_field_type` instead of simply `input_field_tag`.

See the difference?