# Rails4 fields_for and serialized hash. Got 'TypeError: expected Hash (got String)'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, hash, ruby-on-rails-4

I have serialized the attribute properties of Product

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :properties, Hash
```

Product table (sqlite3) has the text column 'properties' containing something like:

```
---
:article: shirt
:size: L
:color: red
```

When I retrieve properties of a product from console I obtain an hash that I can modify and save without any problem. Ruby serializes and deserializes it flawlessly.
Then I tried to build a _form.html.erb with one text_field for each property using fields_for:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
[....]
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :properties, OpenStruct.new(@product.properties) do |property_form| %>
      <%= f.label :properties %><br />
      <% @product.properties.keys.each do |k| %>
        <%= property_form.label k %><br />
        <%= property_form.text_field k, :value => @product.properties[k] %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I edit a product, this code creates 3 text_fields filled with the correct values, but when I try to save it I get:

> "ERROR TypeError: expected Hash (got String) for param 'properties'"

What's wrong? I've read a lot of similar problems with some solutions and I followed different approaches like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521328/how-to-set-up-form-for-a-hash-in-rails) or suggested in [Railscast#403](http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms), but I've always crashed into this kind of error. I'm probably missing something, but I can't find what. Any idea?
(ruby-2.0.0-p247, Rails 4.0.0)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since I was stuck and needed a rapid solution, I used a simple workaround: I created one variable 'property_n' for each text_field and copied it into the hash before saving the object.
Now Edit form is something like this:

```
<% for i in 0..max_num_of_properties %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "property_#{i}".to_sym %><br>
    <%= f.text_field "property_#{i}".to_sym %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and Product class is:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :properties, Hash

  before_save do
    self.properties = {}
    property_names = ProductType.find(product_type_id).get_property_names()
    property_names.each_with_index do |name, index|
      self.properties[name] = get_property(index)
    end
  end

  def get_property(index)
    send("property_#{index}")
  end
```

Hash now serializes flawlessly. With some lines of JS I show the right number and names of properties (from ProductType) in the edit form.
I know it's not the perfect solution, but it may possibly be useful to someone...